# Solution set of this linear system in reduced row echelon form.

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

So we have this matrix:

$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 2 & 1\\
 0 & 1 & -1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}$

Does this matrix have infinitely many solution sets? How do I know? Is it because there are more variables than equations?

Here's my solution. Is this right?

let $ z = t$
so $y = 2 + t$

$x = 1 - 2t$

Is this right?

Comment: Well, you have $$y = 2 + z \\ x = 1 - 2 z$$ $z$ is a free variable, so you can call it $t$ and your result is correct.

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Comment: In the future, please take the time to enter important parts of your question as text instead of pasting pictures of them. Images are neither searchable nor accessible to screen readers. I find it hard to imagine that it would’ve taken you longer to type in that matrix and couple of lines of text than it did to take the picture, crop it, upload it and link it into your question.

Comment: A matrix doesn’t have a solution set; the system of equations that it might represent does.

Answer (score 2):

We want to find all solutions to $x+2z=1$ and $y-z=2$. We can re-write this as $x=1-2z$ and $y=2+z$. Now it is clear that we can pick and number for $z$ and it will give us unique numbers for $x$ and $y$. Thus there are infinitely many solutions of the form

$$\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1-2t\\2+t\\t \end{bmatrix} $$

for $t\in\Bbb R$. So yes, your answer is correct.

In general an $m\times n$ matrix is a map $\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R^m$. The rank tells you the dimension of the image, and the number of columns minus the rank tells you the dimension of the kernel. The dimension of the kernel is exactly the dimension of the number of solutions to a particular equation $Mx=b$, so in this case the solutions are $1$-dimensional, so there are infinitely many.

Comment: Is a system of 3 variables and two equations always with infinite solutions?

Comment: "finitely many solutions" pretty sure it's a typo and you meant infinitely as your answer makes sense using the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Let's solve the augmented matrix
$$
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 2 & 1\\
0 & 1 & -1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}$$
i.e. 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 2 & 1\\
0 & 1 & -1 & 2
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y \\
z \\
-1
\end{bmatrix} =
0$$
That is 
$$\begin{cases}
x + 2z -1 &= 0 \\
y -z -2 &= 0
\end{cases}$$
Since this is a system of two equations in three unknowns, we have to parametrize in terms of one unknown, let's say $z = t$, then we get from the first equation
$$x = 1 -2t$$
and from the second equation
$$y = t+2$$
So the solution set is 
$$\lbrace 
t \in \mathbb{R}: \
\begin{bmatrix}
1 -2t \\
t+2\\
t
\end{bmatrix}
\rbrace$$
Hence, your answer is correct.

Comment: Is a system of 3 variables and two equations always with infinite solutions?

Comment: Yes since the rank of the matrix is at most $2$ (the original matrix or the augmented matrix by omitting the last column).